# Localhost messed up

Tags: webserver, localhost, settings, wamp

I work with my WAMP local web server for half a year now, but when I started it today it didn't work anymore. It says: "Service offline", but when I click "Put Service Online" it says it has already started.

I didn't know what to do so I just tried all services, did some tutorials and I changed the configuration of, well, my computer...

I want everything that has to do with my localhost to be gone, so also the settings in the IIS to be removed, how can I do this or does anyone of you guys know a good tutorial about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open file `httpd.conf` through wamp tray icon

Find:

```
# onlineoffline tag
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Change to:

```
# onlineoffline tag
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
```

and restart